# How to remove 1px from div with svg?

Tags: html, css

I need to remove this 1 px line in div, maybe change height, but when I try to do something, nothing changes...
[Check image there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1z6M.png)

```
<div class="main-head wave-container">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8 p-2" style="color: white;">
            <h1 style="font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif; font-size: 50px;">...</h1>
            <p style="font-family: 'Mitr', sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-size: 22px">....</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 p-2" data-aos="fade-up">
            <img src="{{asset("/storage/img/uploads/pkjd-logo-balts.png")}}" alt="Logo" id="main-head-logo" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
    <path fill="#fff" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,64L80,53.3C160,43,320,21,480,42.7C640,64,800,128,960,138.7C1120,149,1280,107,1360,85.3L1440,64L1440,320L1360,320C1280,320,1120,320,960,320C800,320,640,320,480,320C320,320,160,320,80,320L0,320Z"></path>
</svg>
```

```
.wave-container svg {
display: block;
transform-origin: bottom;
animation: animateWave 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) forwards;
}
.wave-container {
position: relative;
color: #FFF;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Maybe your browser is not at 100% zoom?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan it is at 100%, on the phone same problem.

Comment: Maybe your PNG logo image has that pinky line on top? This issue is not reproducible, I'm afraid... Do you have a live link to share? Have you tested in all browsers?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan https://pkjd.eu/new-main Check it. In Safari you can see it always, but in Google Chrome you need to zoom a little bit.

Comment: Hm... the issue is not reproducible in Chrome (all zoom levels) - but is reproducible in Firefox 101.01 at 100% zoom (Windows 11)

Comment: Yeah, thats magic :D

Comment: Dirty fix: set your view box to 1px less height: `viewBox="0 0 1440 319"` (instead of `viewBox="0 0 1440 320"`). Seems line the path for hat specific SVG does not align perfectly... on that specific element size. Not quite sure.

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks. I guess, it will be ok with this fix.

Comment: I'm not sure... Try now if the issue will not escalate to another browser...

Comment: Yeah, now in Firefox the 1px is exaggerated and extra visible Sorry. Wrong suggestion.

Comment: idk, maybe there is another way how to fix that?